# Installing Android SDK for Android Studio

Tags: 15.04, android-studio, android-sdk

I've already a working Android Studio 1.2 installed on my computer. But seems there is no installed SDK tools on my computer, so when I try to launch the Android Studio a dialog pops up saying please specify SDK location.

I've searched whole of https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html page and sounds there are only two options.

- Android Studio bundle, including IDE and SDK tools
- Stand-alone SDK tools for IDEs other than Android Studio. (ADT for example).

But I need a third option that only provides *SDK tools only tailored for Android Studio*. Thus my question would be is there any other repository by which this option is provided?

If there is no such repository, I should download that bundle file again. (Seems would be a nightmare with my snaily network speed `:)` )

Please note that I've tried already stand-alone SDK with Android Studio, but seems they couldn't couple together.

Comment: can't you change the path to sdk and see if it works?

Comment: @Ron I don't have a SDK installed, I want to download it from the Internet.

Comment: what's the error when you install `android-sdk_r24.2-linux.tgz`?

Comment: @Ron It says Android SDK directory is not valid.

Comment: May be you should select the `sdk` folder as such for the sdk home folder and if that did not work try reinstalling Android Studion (if you still have the installer)

Comment: @Ron Unfortunately I don't have the installer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23681/discussion-between-abforce-and-ron).